# Using array of char from another method to count occurances - char can't be converted to char[] -

Tags: java, arrays, char

Please be kind as I am very new to Java (and programming in general).

I am trying to write a method that will count the occurrences of grades, and I think I have it figured out, but I am losing my mind trying to test it (i TestingPage) I get the error 'char can't be converted to char[]'
The method with the grades (getGrades), converted int to char based on the level of grades (marks).

Im sure the solution is simple, but I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong, or what I need to include or take out to test it.

```
public class ProcessMarks {
    Marks testMarks = new Marks(); 
    int[] marks = testMarks.getMarks();

    //Method to create a new array of grades based on marks array
    public static char getGrades(int marks[]){
        int a = 90;
        int b = 75;
        int c = 60;
        int d = 50;
        int e = 45;
        char[] grades = new char [marks.length];
        char gradedMarks = grades[0]
        //else is F for fail! 
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++){
            if (marks[i] >= a)
                grades[i] = 'A';
            else if (marks[i] >= b && marks[i] < a)
                grades[i] = 'B';
            else if (marks[i] >= c && marks[i] < b)
                grades[i] = 'C';
            else if (marks[i] >= d && marks[i] < c)
                grades[i] = 'D';
            else if (marks[i] >= e && marks[i] < d)
                grades[i] = 'B';
            else 
                grades[i] = 'F';
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < grades.length; n++) {
            System.out.print(grades[n] + " ");
            if (n % 10 == 9)
                System.out.println();
        }

            return gradedMarks;
              
            }
    
    //Method to establish total occurrences of each grade
    public static char gradesDistn (char getGrades[]){
      char[] grades = getGrades;
      char gradesDistn = 0;

         int a = 0;
         int b = 0;
         int c = 0;
         int d = 0;
         int e = 0;
         int f = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
             if (grades[i] == 'A')
                 a++;
             else if (grades[i] == 'B')
                 b++;
             else if (grades[i] == 'C')
                 c++;
             else if (grades[i] == 'C')
                 c++;
             else if (grades[i] == 'D')
                 d++;
             else if (grades[i] == 'E')
                 e++;
             else
                 f++;
         }
         System.out.println("A: " + a);
         System.out.println("B: " + b);
         System.out.println("C: " + c);
         System.out.println("D: " + d);
         System.out.println("E: " + e);
         System.out.println("F: " + f);
         
         return gradesDistn;
         }
     }


public class TestingPage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] marks = Marks.getMarks(); 
        char[] grade = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks); // char cannot be converted to char[] 
        
      
        int median = ProcessMarks.getMedian(marks);
        int min = ProcessMarks.getMin(marks);
        int range = ProcessMarks.getRange(marks);
        int mean = ProcessMarks.getMean(marks);
        int mode = ProcessMarks.getMode(marks);
        char grades = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks);
        int distribution = ProcessMarks.gradesDistn(grade);
        
        System.out.println(range);
        
       
           }
     
}
```

Comment: You expect a `char[]` return type when calling `getGrades()` the first time. You will get a `char` returned from the called method as you specified. Thats where your types mismatch. Are you sure, that you don't want to return `grades` instead of `gradedMarks` (which is never actually altered) in your `getGrades()` method?

Comment: I'm guessing that is what I am trying to do, however I have just assigned the return value as 0, because I couldn't figure out how to return the array grades[]. When I print getGrades in the main method it works and the grades array prints, not the 0 value fro the return statement. 
I have just updated it to this. char gradedMarks = grades[0];

Answer (score 0):

In your `TestingPage`  class `void main` method you are doing this :

```
char[] grade = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks);
```

This means you are expecting a `char[]` in return but the method `getGrades` returns only a `char` as below :

```
public static char getGrades(int marks[]) { }
```

What data-type a method will return you need to catch the response in the exact same data-type.

If you do the below, your error [***char cannot be converted to char[]***] goes :

```
char grade = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks);
```

But I can see many other flaws as well in your methods.

Example : Like the getGrades() returns gradedMarks which is never populated except the declaration point. It will always return the same value.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! I should have been a bit more specific maybe. I am trying to test the gradeDistn being int distribution = ProcessMarks.gradesDistn(grade); however I need to use the array I created in getGrades in gradeDistn.

Comment: Oh and I also am a bit confused about what needs to return, you comment has picked up on that. I have to have a return statement to allow the method to work properly, but in getGrades, the return value doesn't seem to do anything and I get the appropriate results. Should I be putting my return statement in each loop instead? Most of my other methods have had specific and singular values to return so they have all made sense, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method:

```
char[] grade = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks);
```

`getGrades()` returns `char`, but you assign it to the array of chars `char[]`, which is not compatible and cannot even be implicitly casted.

Generally, remember, that type `T` and type `T[]` are completely different types.

Comment: Thank you! I am still confused, because I thought getGrades(marks) was an array, as I have used int[] marks = testMarks.getMarks(); above.
Similar to how I have used int[] marks = Marks.getMarks(); to get the array of marks.

Comment: You haven't provided the `getMarks()` method, but it doesn't matter here what it does. Your question is about `char` cannot be assigned to `char[]`. Your statement `char[] grade = ProcessMarks.getGrades(marks);` declares a variable of type char array, but then assigns to it what `getGrades` return, which is `char` and not the array of chars.

Comment: OK thank you. So I need to figure out how to get the getGrades method to returns a char[ ] instead of char. I thought I had done this as it prints the whole array when tested.  I shouldn't assume that because the method returns the right output, doesn't mean the return value is the right type. How confusing!! :)

Comment: Not necessarily. This depends on how you want to implement it. Maybe you want to keep it returning whatever it returns? it's up to you and your implementation. Just remember that **whatever your method returns** is the value which you tried to assign to another type. And types, at least, should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Jandie, as discussed offline - you need to define the type as an array. The above answers should be accepted as they are spot on.

`public static char getGrades(int marks[]){`

becomes

`public static char[] getGrades(int marks[]){`